# Android multidex doesn't work with Threat Metrix in an external AAR

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, proguard, android-multidex

We are trying to use an `aar` file in our Android app supplied by a third party. That file has a dependency in it for ThreatMetrix (TrustDefender-4.1-176). We are using MultiDex in our app. When we try to run connectedAndroidTest via gradle on our Macs, we are getting the following error:

```
./gradlew connectedAndroidtest

> Task :app:multiDexListDebugAndroidTest FAILED
D8: Class content provided for type descriptor com.threatmetrix.TrustDefender.internal.ˏ$ι actually defines class com.threatmetrix.TrustDefender.internal.ˏ$ι

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:multiDexListDebugAndroidTest'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Error while merging dex archives:
```

The ThreatMetrix library in the provided aar file has already been processed using proguard, but the encoding made it that some class names don't match their respective file names. This seems to break our MultiDex.

I've tried all kinds of things in `proguard-rules.pro` and `multidex-keep-rules.pro`. Example:

```
-dontwarn com.threatmetrix.TrustDefender.**
-dontnote com.threatmetrix.TrustDefender.**
```

But nothing seems to work. Is there a way to configure multidex to ignore this error?

Comment: Hi did you find any solution to make this work ?

Comment: We had to go to the supplier of the library that we were using (they were using Threat Metrix) and ask him to include the following proguard rules. When they built their library with those rules, it fixed our issue. ```-useuniqueclassmembernames
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames```